# Get Run time error 429 for CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection") while connection to HP-ALM:Quality Centre 12.01

Tags: vba, excel, hp-alm

I wrote a piece of code for connecting to HP-ALM: Quality Centre 12.01.The basic line of code

```
Set tdConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
```

Gives me the error

> Run time error 429
>
> ActiveX component can't create object.

In the Excel tools references I have already selected Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.0 library.

Comment: Whatever "TDApiOle80.TDConnection" is, it does not live inside *Microsoft  ActiveX Data Object 2.0 library*

Comment: Google says you are trying to use something that lives inside OTAClient.dll so you need to ensure you have that dll and that it has been registered with regsvr32.

Comment: How to register it and get the dll

Comment: Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install the HP ALM Connectivity Tool (TDConnect.exe). You should be able to access its documentation via *https://yourqcserver/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html* and download it via *https://yourqcserver/qcbin/PlugIns/TDConnectivity/TDConnect.exe*. Maybe it was called somewhat different in ALM 12.01, but the name of the exe should be the same.